# Very high latency with getstream.io

Tags: getstream-io

I am using the official low level node.js api(https://github.com/GetStream/stream-js).
Every get request delays between 800ms and 1300ms. even tough I am located in Argentina and using the free plan i know that is not normal. My app is in the region us-east, here is a little snippet of my code:

```
 function getFeed(userId, lang, lastId){
   logger.error("get user feed for: " + userId + ", lang: " + lang);
   userFeed = client.feed('timeline', lang+userId);
   var restrictions = [{limit:10}];
   if(lastId)
      restrictions.push({id_lt: lastId});
  return userFeed.get(restrictions); //returns promise
 }
```

Comment: can you describe what kind of hosting setup you're using in Argentina, what your bandwidth speed is, etc.?

Comment: I am testing the product in my local machine using ubuntu 16.04 lts with node v7.10.0. Here are my network details: http://www.speedtest.net/my-result/6487836868

Comment: Is the code snippet (and the timing) you've posted running on a Node app in us-east or on your local machine in Argentina (either dev-env app or in browser)? When you say "request delay" do you mean the HTTP connection time, time to first byte, or the overall HTTP response time?